# How can I update Node.JS through JXCore?

Tags: node.js, jxcore

I'm getting this error when trying to use the Steam API:

```
var cryptedSessKey = require('crypto').publicEncrypt(fs.readFileSync(__dirna
^
TypeError: Object # has no method 'publicEncrypt'
at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/psa/var/modules/jxcore-support/native_modules/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:150:42)
at SteamClient.netMsgReceived (/usr/local/psa/var/modules/jxcore-support/native_modules/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:106:26)
at Connection.emit (events.js:82:15)
at Connection._readPacket (/usr/local/psa/var/modules/jxcore-support/native_modules/node_modules/steam/lib/connection.js:50:8)
at Connection.emit (events.js:79:15)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:383:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:379:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:143:31)
at Connection.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:107:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:489:18)
Spawner error: Application exited by itself with code: 8
Spawner info: Subscribing is delayed by 2000 ms.
Spawner info: Subscribed successfully: Successfully subscribed process 25525 to the monitor.
```

The fix is to apparently upgrade my node.js to version v0.12. As stated here: https://github.com/seishun/node-steam/issues/121

How can I do this? I'm using JXCore extension for Plesk.

I've tried SSHing in and running update commands but it doesn't seem to recognise node. Do I have to browse to a certain directory? I can't even run `node --version` because it's all within JXCore (I assume).

I have the lastest version of JXCore (Installed v Beta-0.3.0.2).

[image]

I'm assuming I'm just being an idiot somehow but I'm still new to node.js.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on their Github and this was [their response](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/issues/392):

> JXcore v 0.3 is based on Node 0.10. AFAIK that module has node 0.10
>   compatible version too. You should use that. We are planning to bring
>   new crypto API from 0.12 soon.

Therefore, for now, you can't update it.